# Swift variables: best way to handle this string declaration?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm working through the Swift Guided Playground and came across this example.

The example code takes an array of dictionaries (kinds) and searches for the largest number. The exercise is to find both the largest number, and return the number's kind.

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]
var largest = 0

for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
        }
    }
}
print(largest)
```

In this example, 25 is the largest number and is the "Square" kind.

My immediate instinct was to add a new string variable called "largestKind" and declare it after largest(Int).

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]
var largest = 0
var largestKind: String

for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
            largestKind = kind
        }
    }
}
print(largest)
print(largestKind) // error: Variable 'largestKind' used before being initialized
```

However, Swift throws this error stating that I have not initialized largestKind before using it. I suppose setting largestKind equal to kind does not count as initialization?

I found two work arounds to this error:

1. Initializing largestKind with a placeholder string (i.e. var largestKind = "")
2. Treat largestKind as an optional and then unwrap with print(largestKind!)

Example 1:

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]
var largest = 0
var largestKind = ""

for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
            largestKind = kind
        }
    }
}
print(largest)
print(largestKind)
```

Example 2:

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]
var largest = 0
var largestKind: String?

for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
            largestKind = kind
        }
    }
}
print(largest)
print(largestKind!)
```

What would be the best practice for fixing this error? Also, why did I get the initialization error when I was setting the value equal to another variable?

Comment: You got the error because there was no guarantee that largestKind would be initialized. Btw in your example 2, don't force unwrap your optional. If it is not initialised your app would crash. Use `if let largestKind = largestKind {` or provide a default value using the nil coalescing operator `largestKind ?? "none"`

Comment: If `largestKind` is *optional*, then `largest` should be as well.  Since the author of the original code chose to just start `largest` at `0`, the logical equivalent for `largestKind` would be the empty `String` `""`.  For such a simple example where you know some value is going to be picked up, I wouldn't bother with the *optional*.

Answer (score 1):

I can look at your data and your code and I can see that largestKind will always be initialised, because there are numbers > 0.

However, according to the rules that the compiler uses, there is no guarantee that largestKind is ever set. That's why you get an error message at compile time: Because according to the compiler, largestKind might not be initialised when it is used.

You can fix this in two ways: One, you initialise var largestKind = "". Now largestKind is always initialised. Two, you declare var largestKind: String? Now it is an optional string, and optionals are always automatically initialised to nil.

In the second case, if you call print(largestKind!) you tell the compiler "please crash my program at runtime if largestKind is nil". That's an accident waiting to happen. Forced unwrapping using ! should only be used if you are absolutely sure that it cannot be nil. You could a check around the print like `if let largestKind = largestKind { }` or you could write `print (largestKind ?? "")` which will print largestKind if not nil, and an empty string otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example I would say var largestKind = "" because you will always have a largest kind value. However, in another situation, where this is not guaranteed, you should use var largestKind: String?

Not sure what you mean with your 2nd question. The error results from var largestKind: String

Comment: You shouldn't use `""` . `String?` or even `String!` would be a better choice, both as currently written, and for the future case where the input can be empty. Writing it as `""` today would make it work today, but silently fail in the future in a weird way.

Answer (score 0):

You got the error because there was no guarantee that largestKind would be initialized. Btw in your example 2, don't force unwrap your optional. If it is not initialised your app would crash.

The best practice is to unwrap your optional using `if let` or `guard let`.

```
if let largestKind = largestKind {
    // your code
}
```

or provide a default value using the nil coalescing operator

```
largestKind ?? "none"
```

---

Note that if your intent is to find the maximum value there are higher functions exactly for this purpose. You can compactMap your dictionary values to find their maximum value and them get the maximum key value pair:

```
if let (kind, largest) = interestingNumbers.compactMapValues({$0.max()}).max(by: {$0.value < $1.value}) {
    print("kind:", kind, "largest:", largest)  // kind: Square largest: 25
}
```